# SQL - Remove Duplicate Rows Based on a Single Column

Tags: sql, duplicates, subquery

I have a dataset with duplicate IDs, different scores, and different days like this

[image]

I want one row per ID based on the maximum value of day. This is the output I want

[image]

The query I currently have is not deduplicating because there are multiple scores per ID. I am trying to use a subquery in the where clause like this

```
select distinct
    ID,
    score, 
    day
from 
    table A
where 
    day in (select max(day)
            from table A
            group by ID)
```

The subquery obviously returns only one ID per row, but when I add in the score, I am still getting duplicates.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does ID 12345 have a max day of 5? `7 > 5`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if an ID has the same max value on two different days?

Comment: You could have a correlated subquery, instead of the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses a common table expression, which is supported by most DBMS, for getting the max day per ID. Then join to it on both ID and Day.

```
with maxCTE as (
 select id, max(day) as max_day
   from table1
  group by id  
  )
select t.*
  from table1 t 
  join maxCTE m 
    on t.id = m.id 
   and t.day = m.max_day
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RANK()` window function to get each ID's max day row(s).

```
select ID, score, day
from (
  select a.*, rank() over (partition by ID order by day desc) rnk
  from table A
) dt
where rnk = 1
```

(Will return both rows if the same max day value is found twice for an ID. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead if you want only one of them.)